# Restructuring a pandas dataframe (convert dates in rows to columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following contents

| Room | Position | Sensor | Measuring Time | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Living Room | A1 | 111 | 27-12-2021 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 0.9 |
| Living Room | A2 | 112 | 27-12-2021 | 2.1 | 2.1 | 1.9 |
| Living Room | B1 | 113 | 27-12-2021 | 1.5 | 1.4 | 1.4 |
| Living Room | B2 | 114 | 27-12-2021 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.9 |
| Bed Room | A1 | 211 | 27-12-2021 | 4.2 | 4.5 | 4.4 |
| Living Room | A1 | 111 | 29-12-2021 | 0.9 | 1.1 | 0.8 |
| Living Room | A2 | 112 | 29-12-2021 | 1.9 | 1.8 | 1.7 |
| Living Room | B1 | 115 | 29-12-2021 | 1.4 | 1.3 | 1.2 |
| Living Room | B2 | 114 | 29-12-2021 | 1.7 | 1.5 | 1.7 |

I want to convert the dataframe as below

| Room | Position | Sensor | Value | 27-12-2021 | 29-12-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Living Room | A1 | 111 | Value1 | 1.1 | 0.9 |
| Living Room | A1 | 111 | Value2 | 1.2 | 1.1 |
| Living Room | A1 | 111 | Value3 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| Living Room | A2 | 112 | Value1 | 2.1 | 1.9 |
| Living Room | A2 | 112 | Value2 | 2.1 | 1.8 |
| Living Room | A2 | 112 | Value3 | 1.9 | 1.7 |
| Living Room | B1 | 113 | Value1 | 1.5 | N/A |
| Living Room | B1 | 113 | Value2 | 1.4 | N/A |
| Living Room | B1 | 113 | Value3 | 1.4 | N/A |
| Living Room | B1 | 115 | Value1 | N/A | 1.4 |
| Living Room | B1 | 115 | Value2 | N/A | 1.3 |
| Living Room | B1 | 115 | Value3 | N/A | 1.2 |
| Living Room | B2 | 114 | Value1 | 1.8 | 1.7 |
| Living Room | B2 | 114 | Value2 | 1.7 | 1.5 |
| Living Room | B2 | 114 | Value3 | 1.9 | 1.7 |
| Bed Room | A1 | 211 | Value1 | 4.2 | N/A |
| Bed Room | A1 | 211 | Value2 | 4.5 | N/A |
| Bed Room | A1 | 211 | Value3 | 4.4 | N/A |

I tried using pivot but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

If you have duplicates, use `pivot_table` and an `agg` function:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['Room', 'Position', 'Sensor'],
                     columns=['Measuring Time'],
                     values=['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'],
                     aggfunc='last') \
        .rename_axis(columns=['Value', None]).stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

You can use `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot(index=['Room', 'Position', 'Sensor'],
               columns=['Measuring Time'],
               values=['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']) \
        .rename_axis(columns=['Value', None]).stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
           Room Position  Sensor   Value  27-12-2021  29-12-2021
0   Living Room       A1     111  Value1         1.1         0.9
1   Living Room       A1     111  Value2         1.2         1.1
2   Living Room       A1     111  Value3         0.9         0.8
3   Living Room       A2     112  Value1         2.1         1.9
4   Living Room       A2     112  Value2         2.1         1.8
5   Living Room       A2     112  Value3         1.9         1.7
6   Living Room       B1     113  Value1         1.5         NaN
7   Living Room       B1     113  Value2         1.4         NaN
8   Living Room       B1     113  Value3         1.4         NaN
9   Living Room       B1     115  Value1         NaN         1.4
10  Living Room       B1     115  Value2         NaN         1.3
11  Living Room       B1     115  Value3         NaN         1.2
12  Living Room       B2     114  Value1         1.8         1.7
13  Living Room       B2     114  Value2         1.7         1.5
14  Living Room       B2     114  Value3         1.9         1.7
```

Comment: Beautiful answer +1.

Comment: @Corralien
Thanks for the answer. It works for the sample set I provided.
However, when I have multiple entries in rooms, for example bed room and bath room, pandas raise an error saying Index contain duplicate entries. How could I solve this?

Comment: If you have duplicate values, you have to take a decision. Suppose for a same date and a same combination like ` Living Room, B2, 114, Value3`, you have to values like `1` and `2`. What do you want to do? Take the mean (1.5), the first (1), the last (2), the min (1), the max (2), ...

Comment: @Corralien I have updated the input dataset with an additional rooms data. Sorry for the incomplete set which was provided earlier.

Comment: @aj7amigo. I just need to answer to my question :)

Comment: @Corralien If there are duplicates on same date, I want to take the last entry on that date.
Thanks

Comment: @aj7amigo. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?